# Writing and Reading ArrayList<File> into android cache memory

Tags: android, file, caching, arraylist, android-file

I have a arrays of apk files, what I need is to do write the apk files of ArrayList into cache storage and read it back again as same ArrayList. I know how to insert a single file and retrieve back again from the cache. But whereas ArrayList objects as concern I completely stuck up with the solutions and methodology. Please help me. I am using following code for read and write into cache memory. Any modification or slight changes in my code will be more helpful to me. Thanks in advance

**Actual code for Read and write single File**

```
//Write to cache dir

FileWriter writer = null;
try {
    writer = new FileWriter(tmpFile);
    writer.write(text.toString());
    writer.close();

    // path to file
    // tmpFile.getPath() 

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//Read to cache directory
String TMP_FILE_NAME = "base.apk";
File tmpFile;

File cacheDir = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();
tmpFile = new File(cacheDir.getPath() + "/" + TMP_FILE_NAME) ;

String line="";
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try {
    FileReader fReader = new FileReader(tmpFile);
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(fReader);

    while( (line=bReader.readLine()) != null  ){
        text.append(line+"\n");
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Modified code for my requirement to insert** `ArrayList<File>`

```
String tempFile = null;
public void writeFile(ArrayList<File> files(){

 for(File file: files) {
            FileWriter writer = null;
            try {
                writer = new FileWriter(file);
                tempFile = file.getName().toString();
                writer.write(file.getName().toString());
                writer.close();

                // path to file
                // tmpFile.getPath()

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
}
```

**This is where I stuck completely to read as ArrayList**

What i tried is

```
String line="";
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            FileReader fReader = new FileReader(tempFile);
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(fReader);

            while( (line=bReader.readLine()) != null  ){
                text.append(line+"\n");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my own answer for my question after a longstruggle from the [blog](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/04/07/caching-objects-in-android-internal-storage/).

**To Write a** `ArrayList<File>`:

```
public static void createCachedFile (Context context, String key, ArrayList<File> fileName) throws IOException {

        String tempFile = null;
        for (File file : fileName) {
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput (key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream (fos);
            oos.writeObject (fileName);
            oos.close ();
            fos.close ();

        }
    }
```

**To Read a** `ArrayList<File>`

```
public static Object readCachedFile (Context context, String key) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput (key);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream (fis);
        Object object = ois.readObject ();
        return object;
    }
```

**Final code in my Activity**

```
 createCachedFile (MainActivity.this,"apk",adapter.getAppList ());

 ArrayList<File> apkCacheList = (ArrayList<File>)readCachedFile  (MainActivity.this, "apk");
```